# STM32 ADC sampling with timer and DMA and send data to computer with USB

Tags: stm32, adc, sampling, dma, processing

I want to sample a 4kHz signal that is produced by a signal generator.

I read 2000 samples in a row and then I send it to computer via virtual serial that is provided by USB of STM32F103C8T6. I set timer 3 in order to trigger the ADC and then I set up a 2000 length buffer for DMA.

When I plot signal on the computer the data is not continuous and there is a problem between the signal.

I also stop ADC at the beginning of  the PeriodElapsedCallback and start it again at the end of it.

Here is the image of my signal:

[image]

The ADC clock is 12MHz. The cycles is set to 28.5 and I use a 12bit ADC. My timer clock is 48MHZ and it counts 30 clocks to trigger the ADC. DMA is set to circular mode. I do not expect these disruptions in my signal because I am taking 2000 samples without any stop.

EDIT:
This is my code. As I mentioned before I stop the DMA in the beginning of the interrupt and start it again at the end.

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
  HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc1);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim3);

  usb_put_arr_int(arr,ARRAY_LENGTH);
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, 1<<13);

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, arr , ARRAY_LENGTH);

}
```

I also change the timer period from 30 to 400 and I got a better result but the problem still occurs. I am suspicious about DMA speed.

[image]

Based on my calculation, the timer triggers the interrupt every:
400/48000000 = 8.33us
and the speed of my ADC is about
(28.5+12.5+2.5)/12000000 = 3.62us

So the ADC speed is faster than the timer. Thus, I expect the timer cannot trigger the ADC before the last sampling had completed.

---

I changed the CDC function according to what @JiříMaier said (I did not change my interrupt code.)

```
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
{
  uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 7 */
  USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;
  if (hcdc->TxState != 0){
    return USBD_BUSY;
  }
  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, Buf, Len);
  result = USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);

  for (uint32_t usbTimeout = 100000; usbTimeout > 0; usbTimeout--) {
    if (hcdc->TxState == 0)
      break;
  }



  /* USER CODE END 7 */
  return result;
}
```

[image]

---

I also changed my code structure and changed my interrupt code according to  @JiříMaier advice and I got the following result. The problem is that if I do not open the serial plotter on the computer in the beginning of the microcontroller start, microcontroller gets stuck if I open the serial plotter later.

[image]

---

When I change the buffer size from 2000 to 1000 everything is OK but I do not know why it has problem with the size of 2000.

In order to complete the documentation, this is `put_arr_int` function:

```
void usb_put_arr_int(uint16_t * number,int len)
{
    #define batch_size 50

        for (int j=0; j < (len/batch_size) ; j++)
        {
            count += j*batch_size;
            char f[batch_size*7];
            sprintf(f,"%hu\n",number[0 + j*batch_size]);
            for(int i=1;i<(batch_size);i++)
            {
                sprintf(f,"%s%hu\n",f,number[i + j*batch_size]);
                count+=i;
            }
            CDC_Transmit_FS(f,strlen(f));
}
```

`len` is always bigger than `batch size`.

Comment: You'll have to post code to get an answer.  I strongly  suspect you have a buffer length/handling problem with the DMA buffer but it is impossible to tell without seeing the code.  If you have the RAM, set up two buffers in memory and in the interrupt handler at the end of the conversions just swap to the other buffer and set a flag.  In a main polling loop, check the flag and process the complete buffer outside the interrupt handler.

Comment: Something else is running at 1/200 of the sample rate. Disable any interrupts with slow handlers while sampling; re-enable them after.

Comment: @DeanFranks, I updated the question.

Comment: @user_1818839, I updated the question

Comment: How is the usb_put_arr_int implemented? The CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*) buf, len) function (which I suppose you use for transmitting buffer) doesn't block until the transmit is finished. It only starts the transfer and code continues immediately. So you are probably overwriting the buffer by new measurement while it is being transmited.

Comment: @JiříMaier but as you can see I stopped the DMA and timer so it does not supposed to transmit new data into DMA. You mean that  CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*) buf, len) does not block the code? But interrupt is not enabled for transmission.

Comment: But if you use (unmodified) CDC_Transmit_FS inside usb_put_arr_int(arr,ARRAY_LENGTH), the function returns immediately after the transfer is started (and not yet finished). So you start the timer and DMA before USB is finished anyway.

Comment: @JiříMaier. That is a subtle point. But how does it transmit the data when it does not use interrupt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this:

in the callback function, stop the timer and DMA and set some "flag" variable:

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
   HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc1);
   HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim3);

   samplingFinished = 1;
}
```

(samplingFinished is uint8_t global variable)

and in main while loop check if samplingFinished is 1.

```
while (1) {
  if(samplingFinished){
    samplingFinished = 0;
    
    // Send data
    
    // Start timer and DMA again

}
```

You can send data using CDC_Transmit_FS from HAL libraries.
That function however doesn't wait until transmit is finished.

You can modify the function (in USB_DEVICE->App->usbd_cdc_if.c) so that it will wait until all data is transmitted.

```
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
{
   uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
   /* USER CODE BEGIN 7 */
     USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*) hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;
     if (hcdc->TxState != 0) {
        return USBD_BUSY;
     }
     USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, Buf, Len);
     result = USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);

     // New code -------------------
     for (uint32_t usbTimeout = 100000; usbTimeout > 0; usbTimeout--) {
       if (hcdc->TxState == 0)
         break;
     } 
    // ---------------------------
   /* USER CODE END 7 */
   return result;
}
```

The code waits until hcdc->TxState is zero, which means it is finished.
If device is not connected to PC (virtual com port is not open), it would never finish, that is why I use the for loop instead of infinite wait.

Comment: I updated the question with your recommend.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use blocking functions (which the modified CDC_Transmit_FS is) in interrupt service routines. Try the method with "flag".

Comment: I updated the code but the point is that maybe the timeout is not enough for 2000 samples. I also tried ```while (hcdc->TxState != 0);``` but it get stuck here.

Comment: I do it like this in my application with 4000 samples and it works fine.

Comment: Is your DMA set in circular or normal mode? It can get in an error state if it attempts to write outside the length of buffer, which happens in normal mode because ADC can read one more sample before you manage to stop it.

Comment: circular mode. I Updated the question thanks a lot but there is a small problem if I do not open serial plotter in my computer.

Comment: Dou you use the "timeout `for` loop" or the `while (hcdc->TxState != 0);` version now?

Comment: I use your for loop .

Comment: So it gets stuck if the virtual com port is not opened on PC? Can you tell where it gets stuck using debugger? Is it inside the `CDC_Transmit_FS`? Or does the ADC send some error interrupt? Maybe there is some wrong setting in ADC or DMA?

Comment: Maybe try setting `Overrun behavior` to `overwritten` in ADC, but I doubt it could have anything to do with it.

Comment: It  gets stuck here `void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}`

Comment: And which function was it going to do before the hard fault happened? Try debugging it step by step from the beginning until it happens.

Comment: In my `put_int_arr` I have a sprintf and I got this `No source available for "sprintf() at 0x800ac8c" No source available for "sprintf() at 0x800ac8c" ` from debugger.

Comment: When I change the DMA buffer size from 2000 to 1000 it works well. I appreciate your help. thank a lot.

Comment: So you send the numbers as text? What does the `put_int_arr` look like? Are you sending all the values at once (using `CDC_Transmit_FS`) or one value at a time in a loop. If it is 2000 values in a loop, then the timeout in `CDC_Transmit_FS` may just be too big. If you convert all to text first, then send, the text may not even fit in RAM. It may be better to send data in binary (just write buffer into `CDC_Transmit_FS`), but I don't know if your "serial plotter" supports it.

Comment: I use adruino plotter. When I remove some of my extra variable it even is working with 2000 samples. It looks that sprintf did not have enough memory. I added out_int_arr.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party on this one but the STM32 DMA has a half-complete callback for exactly this use case.

Basically you set your system up normally, in circular mode for your 2,000 sample example. Then enable and add a handler for your half-complete and complete callbacks.

In the half-complete handler, you transmit the first half of the buffer while the DMA is busy filling the second half.

In the filly complete handler, you transmit the second half of the buffer while the DMA is busy filling up the first half.

This continues for as long as you want to sample, and you just alternate between  which buffer you are sending - which is where the term ping-pong buffers comes from :-)

Answer (score 0):

Agree  I suspect the USB transfer is taking longer than you expect.  Set the ADC up as a separate DMA/interrupt task to fill buffers and never stop transferring into clean buffers.  Then let the USB just transfer the buffers to the PC as they are filled

Comment: I updated the question.